# Yup ValidationSchema Type with ObjectSchema Not Working

Tags: typescript, yup

- yup 0.30.0
- @types/yup 0.29.14

I'm trying to generate a reusable type definition for a Yup `validationSchema` by using `ObjectSchema` but I keep getting an error

Using an example from the Yup docs here
https://github.com/jquense/yup#ensuring-a-schema-matches-an-existing-type

```
interface TestValidationSchema {
  title: string;
}

const validationSchema: Yup.ObjectSchema<TestValidationSchema> = Yup.object({
  title: Yup.string().required()
});

...

 return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
...
```

The error

```
Type 'ObjectSchema<Shape<object | undefined, { title: string; }>, object>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchema<TestValidationSchema, object>'.
  Types of property 'fields' are incompatible.
    Type '{ title: Schema<string, object>; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ title: Schema<string, object>; }'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ title: Schema<string, object>; }'.
```

I tried bumping the version of `Yup` to 32.11 and got a different, but still confusing error that makes me think I'm just using `ObjectSchema` incorrectly

```
Type 'OptionalObjectSchema<{ title: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; }, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<{ title: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>; }>>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchema<TestValidationSchema, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<TestValidationSchema>, AssertsShape<TestValidationSchema>>'.
  The types of 'fields.title' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I just inspected the type returned from the `validationSchema` above, and the below type works. I'm still wondering why the example in the Yup docs isn't working for me though

```
type ValidationSchema = Yup.ObjectSchema<{
  title: string;
} | undefined, object>
```

Comment: Did you create a GitHub issue for them? I'm experiencing the same, let's take it to 'em :-)

Comment: Same problem. Any issue open? I'll hop on the train.

Answer (score 1):

just update yup and @types/yup
@types/yup 0.29.14
yup 0.32.11
works fine

Answer (score 1):

Required does not allow `undefined` or `null`. You apply this to the `title` successfully.

I think the problem is not with the `title`, but with `Yup.object(...)` which allows `undefined`. Try making it `required()` as well.

Read more regarding `Yup.object()` here: https://github.com/jquense/yup#object